# Django - Get products assigned to user

Tags: python, django

In my django project, User can submit products with a form. If the form is valid, this happens.

```
book = form.save(commit=False)    
book.author = self.request.user
book.save()
```

So I set the author of a book to the logged in user. Now I want to make a User Detail Page, where a User can see his submitted books. So I need to get every book, that is assigned to the logged in user. Any ideas?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped to see your models, but presumably `Book.author` is a ForeignKey to the User table. In which case you can do this:

```
user.book_set.all()
```

where `user` is a User instance, eg `self.request.user`.

Comment: Hey I'm pretty new to django. You write about the book_set.. So If my Book model is named Book, I can do `user.Book.all()`?

Comment: No, you do `book_set`, like I said. See the documentation on [following relationships backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).